# Discord.py Subcommands without cogs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using the following structure for my commands. Not using cogs.
Is there a way to add subcommands to this?

```
@tree.command(name = "test", description = "just a test")
@app_commands.describe(url="URL")
async def test(interaction, url: str):
    await run_command(interaction=interaction, url=url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a group and then define commands using the group as a decorator. I haven't tested the following code, but I believe it will work:

```py
parent = app_commands.Group(name="parent", description="...")

@parent.command(name="test", description = "just a test")
@app_commands.describe(url="URL")
async def test(interaction, url: str):
    await run_command(interaction=interaction, url=url)

tree.add_command(parent)

# the comnand signature will be "/parent test"
```

Comment: I think the missing @tree.command prevents it from being added to the command tree?

Comment: Yes. In this case, we must add the command to the tree explicity. I updated my answer